# When storing session values in an AJAX call, they are lost when the next page is loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I am using MVC3, and I am trying to do a login page.  I am storing all my details in the session.  If I press 'login' again, it will show the values as being in the session.  When I load another page, or reload the login page, the session is empty.  I have made sure there's no code anywhere in my application that could be clearing the session.  I've found online articles about doing what I am doing, so it seems it should work ? I've set breakpoints in my session_start in app_config, and it's only called the once per session.

Just to add, if I look at the session object, the session id is the same.  Two values are put in the session in the controller, and then 10 or so in the AJAX call.  When I reload the same page, only the 2 values are in the controller, but the AJAX call could see those two values. So, the AJAX call could see the existing session, but the values it adds, are visible if I make the same AJAX call over and over, but gone from a page load.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Cassini just flat out fails some times.  I found some google references that suggested this was true, and while the failure was consistent ( I could see my session values until I got to an authorised page ), after I tried running it in IIS ( which did not work ), it started to work in Cassini.  I ended up abandoning this mechanism anyhow, but, if you have the same issue, I'd suggest that the web server that comes with Visual Studio cannot be trusted.